# Using pytds with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, freetds, pythonista

I am trying to connect to an SQL Server from a version of python (pythonista) that requires that I use pure python drivers. I am able to connect using pytds if I don't use sqlalchemy so I know this works.

However, I would like to be able to use sqlalchemy so I installed sqlaclhemy-pytds but when I try:

```
engine = create_engine('mssql+pytds://' +various params)
```

I get:

> Can't load plugin:
>   sqlalchemy.dialects:mmsql.pytds

What am I overlooking?

Comment: Make sure you're using the same version of python you installed sqlalchemy-pytds for, and that you are using the same virtual environment, if it was installed in such.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it working by adding:
https://github.com/m32/sqlalchemy-tds.git

I thought I got that when I did:

`pip install sqlalchemy-pytds
pip install python-tds`

especially since the pip list showed

`python-tds (1.9.1) - Python DBAPI driver for MSSQL using pure Python TDS (Tabular Data Stream) protocol implementation`

but apparently the sqlalchemy MSSQL dialect is different and is not available via pip and must be imported as sqlalchemy_tds

Thanks to everyone who replied.

Comment: Sounds like a PyPI packaging issue. You may want to [take it up with the developer](https://github.com/m32/sqlalchemy-tds/issues).

Answer (score 0):

According to [the SQLAlchemy dialects page](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/index.html) it looks like you'll need to use the external dialect here:

https://github.com/m32/sqlalchemy-tds

Comment: As my post indicated, I installed sqlalchemy-pytds. Are you suggesting something else? Pip list shows I have python-tds and sqlalchemy-pytds.

Comment: Check your spelling. Did you type `mmsql+pytds` instead of `mssql+pytds`  ?

Comment: Wow, you had me going there for one second. I spelled it correctly.